# Opposite of rinforzando?

Tags: notation, dynamics

Is there a dynamics marking that is the opposite of rinforzando, i.e. the volume comes down as the note is sustained?

I'm adapting some music that uses hairpin decresendoes (sic?) on single notes to represent this, but I think that a text marking would be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sforzando-piano,  is pretty much that. If you put a hairpin under a single note then it's actually an accent, which in fact is also often interpreted as reducing the volume during the note (as opposed to tenuto, where the whole note duration is emphasised).

Both of these indicate that the initial note attack is to be emphasised, mind. If you don't want that, I'm not sure you can get around repeating the dynamic level under the note and having a hairpins follow.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, the opposite would be: *gradually less reinforced*

I do not know the Italian term for this, but without using any text I think the effect could be accomplished with tenuto, gradually lengthening phrase markings, and a decrescendo.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I'm going to put a `dim.` under the note, and a (probably) a dynamics mark on the next note since I don't want the accent implied by `sfp` (c.f. leftaroundabout's answer)